# Database not working when deploying application to hosting - connection string

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, deployment

My MVC4 app keeps returning with
500 - Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. Every time I try to query the database.

For example in my  Account/Login controller  `Membership.ValidateUser()`  caused the 500 error.

I know this because removing that line it no longer returns the 500 error (although it also no longer does anything!)

I have set `customErrors="Off"` and turned off friendly errors on the browser but I am not getting anything more specific than what I mentioned above.

I have instantiated the database and tables on the hosting server and verified with SQL Server Management Studio that the database and tables (and users) are present on the server.

I dont know what else it could possibly be except that the connection string is wrong. Heres what it looks like. Is something wrong with it? If not what else could this be?

```
"Server=[myserver.arvixe.com];Database=[databasename]; User ID=[accountcreatedin_hosting_c-panel]; Password=[password]; Trusted_Connection=[true]; Connect Timeout=[30]"
```

Comment: Make up your mind - **either** use the "integrated" security (`Trusted_Connection=true`) - **or then** you specify a UserID and password - you cannot do both at the same time.....

Comment: thank you marc_s. I removed the trusted_connection attribute but problem persists. Does anybody have anymore ideas? :(

Comment: Change the data source to "." instead. That, or your server (blah.arvixe.com). Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score -1):

I use "localhost" as the Server

Comment: thanks for your reply. I just tried this, the error persists.

Comment: How can you use Localhost when he is asking about deploying it to a server lol?